# Meteor: 'detect' current client template on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build a beta invite system in Meteor that only allows account creation (via any of the `accounts` packages, such as `accounts-facebook` or `accounts-password`) from a certain template, `acceptBetaInvitation`. The trick is that I need to be able to also allow logins for those who have already accepted but deny logging in anyone else.

I've been trying to leverage the [`validateNewUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser) callback, which is ALMOST exactly what I need; I can reject new user creation from here and it won't pollute the `users` collection.

The only thing I'm missing is a way for the `validateNewUser` callback to know if it should be allowed.  Ideally I'd somehow pass this info into the callback from the template, but so far I see no way to do that.  I can do something on the server side when the route is reached (I'm using `iron-router`), but that doesn't help either, since I still need a way for an 'allow' flag of some kind to come into the validation callback.

What am I missing?  Is there another way?  Even if try to roll my own system, `loginWithFacebook` (et al) will try to create a new account unless I somehow tell it not to.  I've been trying to figure out how I might patch `accounts-server` to add a custom field to the callback parameter, but even if possible, I'd rather avoid this.

Comment: how are you sending the beta invitation then? Sending an invite will set `services.password.reset.token` if it's a password based system, and OAuth will require them to authenticate

Comment: I was planning to send invitations with a separate system; the problem is that there would be no user record *at all* yet for the user needing to create an account...

Comment: Though now I'm realizing if I made a stub user record for invited users, that might solve everything.

Comment: Argh. Even if I made a stub user record for invited users, the `user` param that comes into `validateNewUser` will pertain to the Oauth service user object (i.e. Facebook profile info), not the invite user record. That's why it seems like the only way to associate them is at the time of the login attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating my own package: https://github.com/t3db0t/meteor-accounts-invite

This allows you to flexibly validate a login attempt on the server.